# uninstall and reinstall neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

On ubuntu 16.04, when trying to uninstall neo4j I typed:

```
sudo apt-get purge neo4j*
```

However, the neo4j folder and all of the data still exist in

```
/var/lib/neo4j
```

Secondly, I tried to just install the newest version using:

```
sudo apt-get install neo4j
```

and when I checked the version from the commandline I got:

```
neo4j 3.3.4
```

This is what I want, but when I start the service and check the version in the web application (http://localhost:7474/browser/), it says that the neo4j version is still 3.1.4.

So, basically I would like to completely remove neo4j, and download the newest version. What is the recommended way of doing this in ubuntu 16.04.

I'm new to neo4j, so I'm sure I'm missing something. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the instructions [here](https://neo4j.com/download-thanks/?edition=community&release=3.3.4&flavour=unix&_ga=2.155274483.938006617.1522332954-812051532.1507125051) and they really helped.

Specifically, I deleted my old neo4j folder located in /var/lib/, and in it's place, I put the new version (which was downloaded from the link above and the top folder was renamed "neo4j"). I'm rebuilding my database from scratch, so I wasn't concerned about keeping any of the data I had previously (although maybe you could just copy it over to the new neo4j folder, I don't know).

I started the neo4j service by typing

```
/var/lib/neo4j/bin/neo4j start
```

and everything was brand new and seemed to be working. Part of the reason I did a fresh install was because I could not understand how to upgrade based on the documentation. I'll have to look into that more.

I also added the jar file for the corresponding apoc procedures to my plugins folder (/var/lib/neo4j/plugins), and adjusted the neo4j conf file (var/lib/neo4j/conf/neo4j.conf) accordingly:

```
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*
```

and apoc procedures are now being recognized, which is fantastic.

Perhaps there is a better way to have done this, but things seem to be working so far. My database is small right now, so I can build it from scratch easily. Let me know if there is a better way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

well, I have tried the method above and it did not work. Since the main purpose is to use the verison 4.x.x of neo4j, I tried anothor way to reach the same effect.

At first, download the neo4j-community-4.x.x and put it in someplace where you want, then open the config/neo4j.conf file and change some configuration as follows:

```
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=:7688
dbms.connector.http.listen_address=:7475
```

After that, start the neo4j by running `neo4j start` and you shall access the neo4j from browser at `localhost:7475`, it did work for me. As for the old version, just let it go.